# Regex - optional non capturing group not matched

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to match from "Some other data. FlowSessionId: bf4a15d2-86ec-4717-8acc-f7d5229f250f additional data" using the regexp:

```
.*?(?:FlowSessionId:\s([\S]+))?.*
```

The flowSessionId information group is optional. When that is present I extract "bf4a15d2-86ec-4717-8acc-f7d5229f250f" data.

The problem is that when I try to make the group optional (using ? at the end of the non capturing group) I will not receive a group match anymore. See the example here: https://regex101.com/r/FU4IkM/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the non capture group and the square brackets, and either match the part with the capture group, or match the whole line.

```
.*?\bFlowSessionId:\s(\S+).*|.+
```

The pattern matches:

- `.*?\bFlowSessionId:\s` Match as least as possible chars and then `FlowSessionId:`
- `(\S+).*` Capture 1+ non whitespace chars in group 1 followed by the rest of the line
- `|` Or
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tfryC5/1)

```js
const regex = /.*?\bFlowSessionId:\s(\S+).*|.+/;
[
  "Some other data.FlowSessionId: bf4a15d2-86ec-4717-8acc-f7d5229f250f additional data",
  "Some other data. additional data"
].forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(regex);
  console.log(m[1] ? m[1] : m[0]);
})
```

Comment: Or (|) operator I only used in (a|b|c) like syntax. In this case it seems to apply to the left group starting at \b and the right part from "I". What are the grouping/priority rules ?

Comment: @Ghita The left part of the `|` is evaluated first. If the left part has not match, then the right part will be evaluated, which will match the whole line with at least a single character.

Comment: I was asking about general rules as for the more complex case (based on this question) from here https://regex101.com/r/64rpUT/1 the match does not work.. There  are some other groups after the flow match.

Comment: @Ghita In that case, you do not have to use the `.*` as it will match too much and the alternatives can possibly not match as the text already is matched. You could use for example https://regex101.com/r/sRTTSi/1 Or matching the groups in the right order and use a single alternation in case the left part does not match https://regex101.com/r/aZkee1/1

Comment: @FourthB in this case I have 2  match "objects" ?. Wonder if  I can have only one match and just make it so that group 1 is optional (the other ones are required). The separation as you defined works but logically I want to have a match object.

Comment: @Ghita You have 1 match object, where you have to check for the existence of the groups.

Comment: I have there "Match 1" and "Match 2" corresponding to the left and right parts of the OR operator. In code there will be no difference I guess, only checking the existence of the groups match.

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookbehind to match only if the `FlowSessionId:` text exists:

```
(?<=FlowSessionId:\s)(\S+)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=FlowSessionId:\s)` - positive lookbehind for the session ID label; if this fails, the whole regex fails
- `(\S+)` - match and capture the ID (if the lookbehind is a match)

Note that some browsers, notably IE do not support lookbehind.

Comment: It's an interesting construct but my regex match don't want to fail as flowSessionId is optional.

Comment: @Ghita: Understood now. I was not clear from your description that you still want to match.